# Why does the photon propagator contain the metric tensor?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, propagator

The Klein Gordon propagator is (Peskin p-30)
$$
D_F(x-y)=\frac{i}{p^2-m^2}
$$
which is actually the Green's function of the KG field. But a photon contains additionally $g_{\mu\nu}$ in the numerator. I would expect its propagator to be the same as $D_F$ since the photon is gauge boson. Why does it have $g_{\mu\nu}$? Does this somehow follow from the Ward identity?

Comment: You can read "Quantization of the Electromagnetic Field" in Peskin's book(p-294).

Answer (score 2):

Photon has spin 1 :) I am serious. Check it if you don't believe me.
The physical meaning of the photon propagator $\Delta_{\mu \nu}$ is the following:

$$ \Delta_{\mu \nu} (x-y) = \left< A_{\mu}(x) A_{\nu}(y) \right>, $$

where $A_{\mu}$ is the electromagnetic potential form and $\left< ... \right>$ is a shorthand for the vacuum expectation value of the time-ordered operator product (in the non-interacting theory, ofcourse), or, equivalently (in the path integral picture), the following holds for any functional $\Omega[A]$:

$$ \left< \Omega[A] \right> = \int DA \cdot e^{i S[A]} \cdot \Omega[A], $$

where path integral measure $DA$ is defined up to normalizations and the $\left< 1 \right> = 1$ normalization condition is chosen.

This picture is obscured by gauge invariance, because non-gauge-invariant expectations are ill-defined. Probably the best way to deal with this is to eliminate gauge invariance by introducing the gauge-fixing term.

P.S. imagine that you have two spin-0 fields labeled by an index $\phi^a$. The propagator is then a $2\times 2$ matrix $\Delta^{a b}$. This is natural, because $\Delta$ encodes transition rates between two separate degrees of freedom ($a$ and $b$).

P.S.2. You mentioned the Klein-Gordon propagator to be the Green's function of the $\left( \Box + m^2 \right)$ operator. Well, the same holds for the photon propagator.

In the Feynman gauge, field equations are the following:

$$ \Box A_{\mu} = 0 \quad (\forall \mu), $$

which means that the field $A_{\mu}(x)$ is annihilated by the differential operator $\delta_{\nu}^{\mu} \Box$.

The Green function is therefore labeled by two space-time positions ($x$ and $y$) and two indices ($\mu$ and $\nu$) and is exactly

$$\Delta_{\mu}^{\nu}(x - y) = \delta_{\mu}^{\nu} \cdot D_F (x - y); $$

$$\Delta_{\mu \nu}(x - y) = g_{\mu \nu} \cdot D_F (x - y). $$

Comment: Is you D_F the same as the OP's D_F? The OP's D_F has a mass...

Comment: @hft My $D_F$ is the same as the OP's $D_F$ when $m=0$. I can't imagine how this could be unclear from my answer above.

Comment: It's unclear because you never mentioned that you set m=0, whereas the explicit definition has an "m". I can't imagine how you can't imagine this couldn't be unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You just assume vector boson dof more than one and tell metric tensor satisfies this. In fact, I see this point But I would expect how to derive it from gauge invariant lagrangian possibly.

Comment: @hft it should be clear to anybody intelligent, because photon is mass zero ok? I mean no offence. I just think you are carping on me for no reason.

Comment: @Major_Tom that is a very good point (that there might be less than four degrees of freedom, also I don't understand why you expect there to be one). As I mentioned in my answer, the best thing to do is to break gauge invariance explicitly by introducing the so-called gauge fixing term in the lagrangian (this is sometimes called Feynman gauge). This can be done with help of the Faddeev-Popov procedure. Take a look at my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158687/quick-non-rogorous-way-to-obtain-feynman-rules-from-a-lagrangian-in-a-non-abelia/158713#158713.

Comment: @Major_Tom there are actually two independent degrees of freedom (these are called photon polarisations) in the Maxwell lagrangian. The Coulomb-gauge quantization attempts to derive the propagator for those, which renders very complex and non-manifestly-Lorentz-invariant. Also an additional problem arises: there is a non-local interaction. The whole mess is, in fact, mathematically equivalent to just writing the Feynman-gauge propagator everywhere in Feynman rules.

Comment: @Major_Tom this is why it is convenient to break gauge invariance and obtain 4 degrees of freedom. It is pretty easy to derive the $g_{\mu \nu}\cdot D_F$ propagator from here. Now the question becomes why we can do this in the first place. The proof can be done with help of the (mentioned above) Faddeev-Popov procedure. You can find more information on it in almost any QFT textbook, including Peskin-Schreder.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] since photon is spin-zero gauge boson. Why does it have gμν ? Does
>   this somehow about Ward identity?

Photon is not "spin-zero gauge boson". It is "spin one gauge boson".

Comment: Yes it obviously a mistake but photon still a boson and I'd expect propagator as $D_F$

Comment: EM field obeys the KG equation what else i expect? Dirac propagator for fermions?

Comment: Well, for one thing, photons have no mass. But the propagator you wrote does have a mass...

Comment: Set m=0 that is what I expect but the propagator has $g_{\mu\nu} additionally and thats I ask.

Comment: @Major_Tom you have not one, but four **independent** (in Feynman gauge) Klein-Gordon fields. Propagator is therefore a unit $4\times 4$ matrix (Kronecker's delta) times the Klein-Gordon propagator. Lower one index for convenience and you will get your metric tensor. See my answer for more details.